# Tagging a snapshot in AWS lightsail

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to tag AWS Lightsail snapshots?

Comment: Have you tried it? Did it work? This page says you can: [Tags in Amazon Lightsail | Lightsail Documentation](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-tags)

Comment: Hello John, i tried, but i failed, because i dont know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Tags in Amazon Lightsail | Lightsail Documentation](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-tags):

> The following Lightsail resources can be tagged in the Lightsail console:
>
> - Instances
> - Databases
> - Disks
> - DNS zones
> - Load balancers
>
> Important: Snapshots created using the Lightsail console automatically inherit tags from the source resource. A Lightsail resource created from that snapshot will have the same tags that were present on the source resource when the snapshot was created.
>
> The following resources can be tagged using the Lightsail API, AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI), or SDKs:
>
> - Database snapshots
> - Databases
> - **Disk snapshots**
> - ...

So, it appears that tagging Snapshots requires you to use the Lightsail API, or the AWS CLI or programmatically via an SDK.

I used the AWS CLI like this:

```
aws lightsail tag-resource --resource-name WordPress-1-1620563255 --tags key=Department,value=Finance
```

The tag does not appear in the Lightsail console, but when I later ran `aws lightsail get-instance-snapshots`, the tag showed in the response.

As per the 'important' notice above, any tags on the instance will automatically be copied to any Snapshots, so that's probably an easier way to add a tag (if appropriate to your situation).